# TableView issue

Tags: javafx

I'm adding data in table-view in javafx. I'm also setting the table columns as shown, they are working fine. Any comments on where I am wrong?

```
c1 = new TableColumn<String, String>("First Name"); //c1 is column 
c1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<String,String>("Name"));  
table.setItems(value); //table is tableview                          
table.getItems().add("My name");                         
table.getColumns().addAll(c1);
count++;
```

Comment: There is no `Name` property in `String` (no `NameProperty()` method or `getName()` methods are available). What exactly are you trying to show and how do you get the column content given the item?

Comment: I know I am wrong here but what I wanted to do is that I want to add "My name" is R1,C1. If you know how to do it, kindly guide